# How to catch a general Exception based on its string argument in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I am communicating with an API that raises an exception like this: `raise Exception("end of time")`.

How do I catch `Exception` only when the string argument is "end of time"?

I don't want to do:

```py
except Exception:
    pass
```

I want to do something like:

```py
except Exception("end of time"):
    pass
```

However, this does not catch the exception.

Example traceback:

```sh
File "test.py", line 250, in timeout_handler
    raise Exception("end of time")
Exception: end of time
```

Comment: @vaultah The link to the duplicate question is inappropriate as the answer does not apply to Python 3.

Comment: Added another one. Hopefully mgilson will update his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Exception `.args` to filter things if you need to do so:

```
try:
    raise Exception("end of time")
except Exception as e:
    if e.args[0] == 'end of time':
        pass # handle
    else:
        raise
```

Comment: `str(e)` works well too.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre what if `len(e.args) > 1`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the ideal case should have been raising a custom exception. Since that's not the case a workaround can be checking the exception message.

```
except Exception as exp:
    if str(exp) == 'end of time':
        # do something
    else:
        # pass or do something else
```

Comment: The message attribute is only available in Python 2.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Hadn't known that. Updated my answer. Thanks.